# get unit type from grid graphics unit

Tags: r, r-grid

In R and the grid package, is there a way to extract the unit type of a unit?

E.g.:

```
x <- unit(1,'inches')
```

Is there a function that does:

```
unittype(x) # returns 'inches'
```

(Well, I'm sure there is - but what is it?)

cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use `attr(x,"unit")` but I'm honestly not sure if there is a more pithy function for this.

Comment: Aha, I knew there was some simple way to grab the unit out. I kept looking for some sort of function the grid package provided. cheers!